# Is there a way to make a navigation bar, created using a list, sticky?

Tags: html, css, list, css-position, navbar

I made a horizontal nav bar with a list that was modified. It works. But - I want it to be fixed or sticky. Neither seem to work. I know I can do a nav bar with a div and block display, and I can do fixed/sticky that way. But I'm wondering whether I can, and, if not, why I can't do a fixed/sticky this way?
Here's my CSS and HTML below:

```
     list-style-type: none;
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
       }
      li a {
        display: inline;
        display: block;
        float: left;
        width: 150px;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        background-color: #DDDDDD;
        text-align: center;
      }
li a:hover {
  background-color: grey;
border: 3px solid red;
color: white;
font-size: 20px;
}

<ul>
      <li><a href="examplelink1.html">The Clickable Text 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="examplelink2.html">The Clickable Text 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="examplelink3.html">The Clickable Text 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this by adding "position: sticky" or "position: fixed" to the ul tag, just make sure you specify "top: 0" so that the page knows where to bind it. It works in this JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sn69zuq1/10/

```
 list-style-type: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 }

 li a {
   display: inline;
   display: block;
   float: left;
   width: 150px;
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
   background-color: #DDDDDD;
   text-align: center;
 }

 li a:hover {
   background-color: grey;
   border: 3px solid red;
   color: white;
   font-size: 20px;
 }

<ul style="position: sticky; top: 0;">
  <li><a href="examplelink1.html">The Clickable Text 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="examplelink2.html">The Clickable Text 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="examplelink3.html">The Clickable Text 3</a></li>
</ul>
```